# Don't know how to get text field into database with file

Tags: php

So far my script can upload pictures, storing the url in the database.  I don't really know how to add the two other text fields for title and tags though.

```
if($_POST["action"]=="Submit")
    {
        $folder="../../images/images_Submitted/";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filep"]["tmp_name"] , "$folder".$_FILES["filep"]["name"]);

        $fileName = $_FILES["filep"]["name"];
        echo "<p align=center>File ".$fileName." loaded...";            
        $result = mysql_connect("*****", "*****", "*****") or die ("Could not save image name Error: " . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("pwnweb") or die("Could not select database");
        $SQLURL = "INSERT INTO photos (URL) VALUES('/images/images_Submitted/" . $fileName . "')";  
        echo "INSERT INTO photos (URL) VALUES('/images/images_Submitted/" . $fileName . "')";
        mysql_query($SQLURL);

        if($result) 
        { 
            echo " Image name saved into database"; 
        }

        else 
        {

            //Gives and error if its not
            echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
        } 

    }
```

Here is my form:

```
<form action="/../scripts/php/submitButtonPressed.php" method=post enctype="multipart/form-data">

        Title: <input type="text" name="title" size=45><br>
        File:  <input type="file" name="filep" size=45><br>

        Tags:  <input type="text" name="tags" size=45><br>
        <input type=submit name=action value="Submit" size=45>

        </form>
```

Comment: use your `$_POST` values then add them on the insert query

Comment: What is your `photos` table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @user1978142 has pointed out, you can try using `$_POST`. I'll try to go in depth:

Just like `$_FILES`, `$_POST` is an array that stores the values of the elements you pass from the HTML to PHP through their names set in the form. For retrieving said values, access the array using:

`$_POST['`*name of the input*`']`

Then you store the values into variables.

In your code it should be:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$tags  = $_POST['tags'];
```

Finally, add them on the query:

```
"INSERT INTO photos (title, tags) VALUES ('".$title."', '".$tags."')"
```

Comment: You should also be using ``mysql_real_escape_query``

Comment: thanks, this for the most part seems to be working! much appreciated!